# A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance

Tags: hibernate

In my application, a hibernate operation goes like this.
The application updates a parent entity with new values from the request and deletes all the existing (previously inserted) child entities and inserts new child records.

I'm using hibernates `DELETE_ORPHAN` for this, as you can see below.

When i do this, I'm getting the below exception :

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with
>   cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning
>   entity instance: com.childs

I saw similar threads with the problem, and I tried to appy solutions in those threads.  But that didn't work

My Parent entity

```
    public class Parent implements Serializable {

            @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
            @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
            @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "seq")
            private Integer parentId;  //primary key of parent

            ....... 
            ........

            //mapping to child entity
            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch =  FetchType.LAZY)
            @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
            private Set<Child> childs;

            ................
            ...............

}
```

Child entity has a combined key and has a PK entity has shown below

```
public class ChildPK implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -447592368963477750L;

    /** . */
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns( { @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID") })
    @Id
    private Parent parent;

    /**. */

    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="child_seq",    strategy="com.DB2Dialect") 
    @GeneratedValue(generator="child_seq") 
    private Integer childId;

}

child entity goes like this:


public class Child implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 185670997643552301L;

    /** The pol cntct id. */
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Id
    private Integer childId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns( { @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID") })
    @Id
    private Parent parent;

}
```

Java code

```
   ...................
    ..............
    parent.getChild().clear();
    Child child = new Child(); 
    parent.setChild(child);
```

What could be wrong here.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate - A collection with cascade=”all-delete-orphan” was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587482/hibernate-a-collection-with-cascade-all-delete-orphan-was-no-longer-referenc)

Answer (score 58):

Your last snippet of Java code doesn't compile. I guess it looks like

```
parent.getChilds().clear(); // note: you should name it children rather than childs
parent.setChilds(someNewSetOfChildren):
```

Don't do the last instruction. Instead of replacing the set by another one, clear the set and add the new children to the cleared set:

```
parent.clearChildren();
parent.addChildren(someNewSetOfChildren);
```

where the methods are defined as:

```
public void clearChildren() {
    this.children.clear();
}

public void addChildren(Collection<Child> children) {
    this.children.addAll(children);
}
```

The setChildren method should be removed completely, or it should be replaced with the following implementation:

```
public void setChildren(Collection<Child> children) {
    this.children.clear();
    this.children.addAll(children);
}
```

Comment: For @JBNizet I have a similar problem and I applied your solution. Actually, from the 2 solutions you indicated I used the later (in the setter method I clear the children collection - this.children.clear() - and I added the new children - this.children.addAll(children)). This change didn't fix my problem. I still get the "A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance" exception. Do you have an idea why? Thank you very much!

Comment: No, I have no idea. You could ask a question, showing your code, the complete stack trace, etc.

Comment: Perhaps in `setChildren` null check should be added `if (children != null) { this.children.addAll(children);}`

Comment: @lolotron IMO, children should never be null. And ignoring the new children if it is is worse than throwing an NPE to signal the bug

Answer (score 19):

I faced the same issue and get it solved as follows:

1- add **{CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true** in all **@OneToMany** annotations in all entity Childs of that element.

2- Check the **hashcode()** and **equalls()** of those entities, some times they have erros

3- Don't use `parent.setChilds(newChilds);` as the engine will ask for missing the reference to the childs, but use instead use

```
parent.getChilds().clear();
parent.getChilds().add(Child);
```

or

```
parent.getChilds().addAll(Childs);
```

Those steps solved my issue after 4 Hours of research

Answer (score 13):

It worked for me.

1. Cleared all my child entities.
2. Instead of setting the new child entities to my parent object, I have used addAll method to  add the new child entities.

   ```
   parent.getChildren().clear();
   parent.getChildren().addAll(newChildrenList);

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)  

   public Set<Children> getChildren() {
       return this.children;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 8):

instead of `setChilds` use `addAll` ,

from this,

```
    parent.getChilds().clear();
    parent.setChilds(newChilds);
```

to

```
    parent.getChilds().clear();
    parent.getChilds().addAll(newChilds);
```

Comment: where shall these be added ? in the parent Entity or in the child entity?

Comment: in parent entity add all child entity

Answer (score 0):

it change works !

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private List<Role> roles;
```