# HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have PolicyDO and PolicyDocumentDO.relation between them is as follows

```
PolicyDO.hbm.xml

<bag name="listPolicyDocumentDOList" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false"   inverse="true">
            <key column="POLICYSEQ" />
            <one-to-many class="dataobjects.policy.PolicyDocumentDO" />
```

```
PolicyDO.java
protected List<PolicyDocumentDO> policyDocumentDOList = new ArrayList<PolicyDocumentDO>();
 public java.util.List<PolicyDocumentDO> getListPolicyDocumentDOList() {
    return this.policyDocumentDOList;
  }

  public void setListPolicyDocumentDOList(java.util.List<PolicyDocumentDO> list) {
      policyDocumentDOList.clear();
      policyDocumentDOList = list;
  }


    PolicyDocumentDO.hbm.xml

    <many-to-one name="parentGuidObj" class="dataobjects.policy.PolicyDO"  not-null="true" >
            <column name="POLICYSEQ"  />
    </many-to-one>
```

When ever I tried to query something from database like below

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Query query = session.createQuery(strBuff.toString());
List listQuery = query.list();
```

I get following error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance:
```

dataobjects.policy.PolicyDO.listPolicyDocumentDOList

So after googling I did following changes while setting  listPolicyDocumentDOList in PolicyDO

```
public void setListPolicyDocumentDOList(java.util.List<PolicyDocumentDO> list) {
      policyDocumentDOList.clear();
      policyDocumentDOList = list;
  }
```

Then also I am getting above error.
What else I can do to solve this error.
Thanks

Comment: try with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5587892/2586617)

Answer (score 17):

change

```
public void setListPolicyDocumentDOList(java.util.List<PolicyDocumentDO> list) {
    policyDocumentDOList.clear();
    policyDocumentDOList = list;
}
```

to

```
public void setListPolicyDocumentDOList(java.util.List<PolicyDocumentDO> list) {
    policyDocumentDOList.clear();
    policyDocumentDOList.addAll(list);
}
```

Comment: Subtle, but effective. Thanks.

Comment: It's working perfectly, don't know the proper reason behind it, can some help explain it.