# Use @JsonSerialize(using=MySerializer.class) on a @OneToMany Set<Object>

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, spring-data-rest

In a Spring Boot/Spring Data Rest project i have issues to use a custom `JsonSerializer<Set<Object>>` on a @OneToMany property. When i do an HTTP GET /collection request i have the following error:

> Failed to write HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write content: Can not override serializer (through
>   reference chain:
>   org.springframework.hateoas.Resources["_embedded"]->java.util.UnmodifiableMap["analogParameters"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not override
>   serializer (through reference chain:
>   org.springframework.hateoas.Resources["_embedded"]->java.util.UnmodifiableMap["analogParameters"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

Below is an extract of my entity class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="output_parameter_id")
@JsonSerialize(using=InputParametersSerializer.class)
//@Transcient
private Set<InputParameter> inputParameters = new HashSet<InputParameter>();

public Set<InputParameter> getInputParameters() {
    return inputParameters;
}

public void setInputParameters(Set<InputParameter> inputParameters) {
    this.inputParameters = inputParameters;
}
```

And the `JsonSerializer<Set<InputParameter>>`

```
public class InputParametersSerializer 
    extends JsonSerializer<Set<InputParameter>> {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 123L;

    public void serialize (Set<InputParameter> ips, JsonGenerator jg, 
            SerializerProvider sp) 
        throws IOException {

        jg.writeString("Yeah");

    }

}
```

If i remove @OneToMany and define the property as @transient it works as expected.

InputParameter entity has no Repository associated (it is not exported as a rest resource).

How can a make use of a JsonSerializer on a @OneToMany property?

Comment: Does your `InputParameter` refer to the entity extract you have posted??

Comment: No its another entity called "Parameter" (names are similar but they are differents entities)

Comment: IMHO it's better to separate concerns, i.e. having **DTO's** (Exposed via RestController, with json-related annotations) separated from **entities** (Object mapped to database using JPA or Hibernate). See [this nice post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/373284/what-is-the-use-of-dto-instead-of-entity).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar issue while using Spring Boot 2.1.0. Adding a custom serializer, both with `using` and `keyUsing`, works fine, but a custom deserializer with a `@OneToMany` annotated field throws out the same `JsonMappingException: Can not override serializer` message you got, while with an `@ElementCollection` it just plain gets ignored. I suspect Spring Data Rest does some undocumented magic in order to take care of the (de)serialization of these kinds of fields that does not play nice with the addition of a custom deserializer. My workaround to this was adding an extra JSON field through an annotated getter and setter. With your example, it would look like:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="output_parameter_id")
private Set<InputParameter> inputParameters = new HashSet<InputParameter>();

public Set<InputParameter> getInputParameters() {
    return inputParameters;
}

public void setInputParameters(Set<InputParameter> inputParameters) {
    this.inputParameters = inputParameters;
}


@JsonSerialize(using=InputParametersSerializer.class)
public Set<InputParameter> getInputParametersSet() {
    return getInputParameters();
}


@JsonDeserialize(using=InputParametersDeserializer.class)
public void setInputParametersSet(Set<InputParameter> inputParameters) {
    setInputParameters(inputParameters);
}
```

Which will output something like

```
{
...
  "inputParameters" : ...,
  "inputParametersSet" : ...,
...
}
```

While not ideal, serialization and deserialization of this field works as expected.
alternatively, in order to keep the field name, a similar workaround worked with `@ElementCollection` but **not** with `@OneToMany`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="output_parameter_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<InputParameter> inputParameters = new HashSet<InputParameter>();

public Set<InputParameter> getInputParameters() {
    return inputParameters;
}

public void setInputParameters(Set<InputParameter> inputParameters) {
    this.inputParameters = inputParameters;
}


@JsonProperty("inputParameters")
@JsonSerialize(using=InputParametersSerializer.class)
public Set<InputParameter> getInputParametersSet() {
    return getInputParameters();
}

@JsonProperty("inputParameters")
@JsonDeserialize(using=InputParametersDeserializer.class)
public void setInputParametersSet(Set<InputParameter> inputParameters) {
    setInputParameters(inputParameters);
}
```

In the end I had to go with the first approach.