# Hibernate OneToMany configuration. Help needed

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

I have two tables

```
Table Student  Columns (Rollnumber, ....)
Table Phone    Columns (STUD_ID,ID, phonetype, number)
```

Student class is

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Student {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  int rollNumber;

  @OneToMany
  Set<Phone> contacts;
  :
  : // Getter setters
}
```

Phone class is

```
@Entity
public class Phone {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  int id;
  @Column
  String type;
  @Column
  String number;
:
: // Getter setters
```

}

But this is not working

```
        Student s1 = session.get(Student.class, 24);

        Phone p1 = new Phone();
        p1.setNumber("1111111");
        p1.setType("Ghar");


        Phone p2 = new Phone();
        p2.setNumber("222222");
        p2.setType("Office");


        Set<Phone> phoneSet = new HashSet<>();
        phoneSet.add(p1);
        phoneSet.add(p2);

        s1.setContacts(phoneSet);

        session.save(s1);
```

But this does not create record in "Phone" table. In Phone class I do not need Student object. 
What extra configuration needed.

**Partial solution**

Finally I was able to do it. By using "Cascade" and "joincolumn" as follows.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="STUD_ID")
public Set<Phone> getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}
```

Queries are fired as follows ( as expected)

```
Hibernate: select student0_.rollNumber as rollNumb1_3_0_, student0_.ADDR_ID as ADDR_ID4_3_0_, student0_.CLASS_TEACHER_ID as CLASS_TE5_3_0_, student0_.name as name2_3_0_, student0_.surname as surname3_3_0_, address1_.ID as ID1_0_1_, address1_.Country as Country2_0_1_, address1_.details as details3_0_1_, teacher2_.teacherId as teacherI1_4_2_, teacher2_.name as name2_4_2_, teacher2_.surname as surname3_4_2_ from Student student0_ left outer join ADDRESS address1_ on student0_.ADDR_ID=address1_.ID left outer join Teacher teacher2_ on student0_.CLASS_TEACHER_ID=teacher2_.teacherId where student0_.rollNumber=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into Phone (number, stud_id, type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Phone (number, stud_id, type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update Phone set STUD_ID=null where STUD_ID=?
Hibernate: update Phone set STUD_ID=? where id=?
Hibernate: update Phone set STUD_ID=? where id=?
```

But as seen above it fires query "update Phone set STUD_ID=null where STUD_ID=?". What should I do so that it will fire Delete queries? 
Using

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
```

throw exceptions

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.kaushik.winnersoft.data.Student.contacts
```

**Solution**

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="STUD_ID")
public Set<Phone> getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}
```

As mentioned by accepted solution changed the code.

```
s1.getContacts().clear();
Phone p1 = new Phone();
s1.getContacts().add(p1); 
Phone p2 = new Phone();
s1.getContacts().add(p2);
```

Delete queries were fired as well. All queries were

```
Hibernate: select student0_.rollNumber as rollNumb1_3_0_, student0_.ADDR_ID as ADDR_ID4_3_0_, student0_.CLASS_TEACHER_ID as CLASS_TE5_3_0_, student0_.name as name2_3_0_, student0_.surname as surname3_3_0_, address1_.ID as ID1_0_1_, address1_.Country as Country2_0_1_, address1_.details as details3_0_1_, teacher2_.teacherId as teacherI1_4_2_, teacher2_.name as name2_4_2_, teacher2_.surname as surname3_4_2_ from Student student0_ left outer join ADDRESS address1_ on student0_.ADDR_ID=address1_.ID left outer join Teacher teacher2_ on student0_.CLASS_TEACHER_ID=teacher2_.teacherId where student0_.rollNumber=?
Hibernate: select contacts0_.STUD_ID as STUD_ID3_2_0_, contacts0_.id as id1_2_0_, contacts0_.id as id1_2_1_, contacts0_.number as number2_2_1_, contacts0_.stud_id as stud_id3_2_1_, contacts0_.type as type4_2_1_ from Phone contacts0_ where contacts0_.STUD_ID=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into Phone (number, stud_id, type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Phone (number, stud_id, type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update Phone set STUD_ID=null where STUD_ID=? and id=?
Hibernate: update Phone set STUD_ID=null where STUD_ID=? and id=?
Hibernate: update Phone set STUD_ID=? where id=?
Hibernate: update Phone set STUD_ID=? where id=?
Hibernate: delete from Phone where id=?
Hibernate: delete from Phone where id=?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error

```
A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced ...
```

is that Hibernate tracks a collection with `orphanRemoval=true` using a proxy.

So you really have a proxy in your persistent class (when you get a `Student` from a database using `session.get(Student.class, 24)`):

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Student {

  @OneToMany
  HibernateProxySet<Phone> contacts;

}
```

If you do this

```
s1.setContacts(phoneSet);
```

You, obviously, override `HibernateProxySet` by your `HashSet`. Hibernate generates `HibernateException` in this situation, because of it wants to track all changes to the `contacts` using HibernateProxySet.

**How to solve**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Student {

  @OneToMany
  Set<Phone> contacts = new HashSet<>();

}

s1.getContacts().clear();
s1.getContacts().add(p1);
s1.getContacts().add(p2);
```

I have added a `contacts` field initialization by `new HashSet<>()`. It is not mandatory, of course, just for convenience. You can think about using such strategy in every persistent class.

Also you can consider to add an additional method to `Student` to add contacts. You can find additional information here:

[Hibernate - A collection with cascade=”all-delete-orphan” was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587482/hibernate-a-collection-with-cascade-all-delete-orphan-was-no-longer-referenc)