# Hibernate Cascade: Remove child entity when parent entity is saved without the child entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I have a schedule object,which contains a list of DateActiveScheduleItems.I want it so that if I remove a DateActiveScheduleItems item from the list in a schedule object and save that schedule using CrudRepository it removes the DateActiveScheduleItem from the database,at the moment my code does not seem to do that.How should I alter the cascade ?

```
@Entity
public class Schedule {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "usergroup_id")
private UserGroup userGroup;

private String description;


private boolean master;//is this a schedule for all supervalus(true) or one supervalu(false)

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<DateActiveScheduleItem> dateActiveScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<MusicScheduleItem> musicScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<AdvertisementScheduleItem> advertisementScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date dateAdded;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
 //getters setters
}
```

DateActiveScheduleItem

```
@Entity
public class DateActiveScheduleItem {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;



@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id")
private Schedule schedule;
//getters setters}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Orphan Removal** removes corresponding child when you remove it from the relationships. So, if you delete 1 DateActiveScheduleItem  from dateActiveScheduleItems  collection, JPA automatically removes that DateActiveScheduleItem  from database too.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval="true")
private List<DateActiveScheduleItem> dateActiveScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

More on OrphanRemovel [HERE](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-delete-child-entities/)

Comment: Getting an error of " A collection with cascade=”all-delete-orphan” was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance" if you happen to know whats going on there,I will post a question on it but I have to wait until the 90 min timer runs out

Comment: I haven't used this type of cascade. I always used orphanRemoval parameter. Here are someone with same problem as yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587482/hibernate-a-collection-with-cascade-all-delete-orphan-was-no-longer-referenc