# Why it is not alllowable to set a new collection in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

In some cases in my experience I encountered that following usage is wrong:

```
entity.setElements(newCollection);
```

And I get error like this:

["A collection with cascade=”all-delete-orphan” was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance".](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5587482/2674303)

So I have to rewrite it like this:

```
entity.getElements().clear();
entity.getElements().addAll(newCollection)
```

Can you please explain why does it happen?

Is it only orphan related issue?

Answer (score 6):

When you perform `entity.setElements(newCollection)` in java, you actually replace the existing collection with a new one. What happen to elements that were in the existing collection ? They become **orphan**. Then the garbage collector comes into action and removes (i.e. free the memory used by) the **orphan objects**. All this occur in RAM, it's a thread running in the JRE, no database involved so far.

Unfortunately there is nothing like a garbage collector in relational databases. You (or in this case Hibernate) have to explicitly delete **orphan records** using a `delete` statement.

Hibernate will therefore trigger delete statement for each `Collection.remove()` or `Collection.clear()`.

Also, there is no way for Hibernate to intercept the JRE garbage collector action to trigger it's own set of `delete` statements. So when you do `entity.setElements(newCollection)`, Hibernate detects that previous collection has been garbage collected, but it's too late, it has no reference anymore to the oprhan objects, thus it cannot make the `delete` statements.

Comment: I get the feeling that you are on to a good explanation, but not quiete. E.g. the Hibernate session tracks all instances it has fetched (that's how it can guarantees that fetching a given Entity will always return the same object instance). Therefore, these objects are not available for GC, they are held by the session. (At least this is may understanding).

Comment: I'd rather guess that Hibernate tracks the changes to the colletion ITSELF, not the elements inside of it.

Comment: @GPI "Hibernate session tracks all instances it has fetched" - maybe, but in `entity.setElements(newCollection)` the elements are not fetched if it's a lazy-loaded collection.

Comment: @GPI well, if we look at the OP original problem, my question is how can hibernate detect this to begin with and besides using an IdentityHashMap for that List internally, I can't think of another way

Comment: Hibernate usually instanciates specialized collections, e.g. PersistentSet instead of HashSet, and provides Lazy loading with byte code instrumentation (code you can not even "see"). So... If I were to venture a guess, I'd say Hibernate loads an entity, associates its id+class info in some data structure to trakce it, plus a link to all associations. Those associations are mapped by ad-hoc implementations that know if they have been mutated (decorate add/remove calls), so it knows what to flush. Drawback : it does not allow you to replace those collections, hence, the OP"s issue.