# Hibernate exception after adding orphanRemoval attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So after adding `orphanRemoval = true` to `@OneToMany` relationship in one of my entities, I get the following exception when trying to save a new or delete an existing entity which references the one with `orphanRemoval = true` attribute.

The exception I get is:

> A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: fully.qualified.path.to.the.property.with.orphanRemoval.setToTrue

One to many relationship is specified like this:

```
  @OneToMany(
  targetEntity = MyEntity.class,
  fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
  mappedBy = "mappingField_",
  orphanRemoval = true,
  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<MyEntity> myEntities_= new ArrayList<>();
```

I get exception when I try to save and flush the entity:

```
myEntityRepository_.saveAndFlushAndRefresh(myEntityInstance);
```

I couldn't find lot of information about this.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587482/hibernate-a-collection-with-cascade-all-delete-orphan-was-no-longer-referenc)?  Main points: do not set list `myEnitities_` via setter, change it by using add/remove methods, and make sure that your equals/hashCode() methods are implemented correctly (hashCode may change if some of the fields changes)

Comment: @AlexRudenko Thanks for the help, but that wasn't the main cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, the cause was that I created new child entities and referenced parent entity in them, and right after that I would set the children of the parent entity using setter, which would cause previously persisted children entities to be dereferenced and cause the mentioned exception.